# Run knex migration during heroku buildpack

Tags: heroku, knex.js, buildpack

I'm using [the meteor buildpack](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) to deploy my meteor app.

I would like to be able to run a migration with `knex` at the end of the buildpack installation.

I forked the buildpack to add a shell script in the `extra` directory (as mentioned in the README) that contains: `cd .knex && knex migrate:latest --env staging`

Unfortunately, there isn't any `.knex` directory in the buildpack current directory.

I run `ls -a` during the heroku buildpack to display the content of the current directory and there isn't a `.knex` directory:

```
remote: .
remote: ..
remote: app
remote: assets
remote: boot.js
remote: boot-utils.js
remote: config.json
remote: mini-files.js
remote: node_modules
remote: npm
remote: npm-shrinkwrap.json
remote: package.json
remote: packages
remote: program.json
remote: shell-server.js
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a migrations folder, created initially at the CLI with: `knex migrate:make migration_name` then you can trigger a migration to the latest within the app itself using: `knex.migrate.latest([config])` as per the documentation: http://knexjs.org/#Migrations-latest

The config should be as per a `knexfile.js`, I followed an example here for reference: http://www.dancorman.com/knex-your-sql-best-friend/

Comment: One can also add to `package.json` > `scripts`: `"postinstall": "knex migrate:latest"`. Also instead of `postinstall` you can use `heroku-postbuild` to be heroku specific.